# Talking on the phone with usage of my PC

Tags: android

I would like to create an application that can let me talk on the phone with headset connected to my PC.

Is it possible to create such a application/service that can transfer voice of the person I talk to to PC and my voice from PC to the smartphone and then to that person?

I have read some questions about streaming audio both ways but can it be achieved with phone call?

I use Android 4.3.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.  What you are looking for is generally called a soft phone, simply put a phone implemented with software.  The technologies usually used with soft phones is SIP and RPT.  SIP controls setting up the call and RTP carries the voice/video data.

There are quite a few good free open source implementations of soft phones, check out CSipSimple, it would be good start to look at how they implement it, as the task is not trivial.

Comment: If I understand everything correcltly - this is techology for VOIPs. It provides establishing calls and sending data to other user over IP. Is that right? If yes - that's not exactly what I meant. I'd like to use my smartphone just to carry voice to my PC and my PC to carry voice to smartphone. All I want is just simple talking on the phone, but with my PC and headset. 
Sorry, but I'm a little confused about softphones. ;)

Comment: so you want to use your phone as a bluetooth/WiFi headset for a call that was initiated from your PC?

Comment: I'd like to have notification on my PC when phone rings, possibility to answer and talk with usage of my headset. But the most impotant part is talking with headset, rest is only extra feature.